# VB.NET Console program quickly get terminated

Tags: vb.net

I'm pretty new in the environment of VB.NET that uses only consoles. I have a problem regarding my program, the console get quickly terminated. How can I my console from doing that? Thanks.

heres my code:

```
Module Module1
    Dim num1 As Integer = 0
    Dim num2 As Integer = 0
    Dim ans As Decimal = 0
    Dim choice As String


    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("First Number: ")
        num1 = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("Second Number: ")
        num2 = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("[A] Addition")
        Console.WriteLine("[S] Subtraction")
        Console.WriteLine("[M] Multiplication")
        Console.WriteLine("[D] Division")
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your choice: ")
        choice = Console.ReadLine

        If (choice.ToUpper() = "A") Then
            ans = num1 + num2
            Console.WriteLine(ans.ToString)
        ElseIf (choice.ToUpper() = "S") Then
            ans = num1 - num2
            Console.WriteLine(ans.ToString)
        ElseIf (choice.ToUpper() = "M") Then
            ans = num1 * num2
            Console.WriteLine(ans.ToString)
        ElseIf (choice.ToUpper() = "D") Then
            ans = num1 / num2
            Console.WriteLine(ans.ToString)



        End If





    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Insert Console.ReadKey() at the end just before the End Sub line.

Comment: At what point in your code does it get terminated? What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: Please search how to use Option Strict On. Executing mathematical operations with strings is a really bad thing

Comment: Console.ReadKey() pretty works. :) thanks. 

Even I said im new in the VB.NET environment, people keeps downgrading my question. :/

Comment: @akoDwin your question may have been downvoted, as you didn't explain how the behaviour differed from what you expected, so not even "it quits immediately after printing the answer" - similarly, there's no demonstration of what you've tried to try and resolve the issue yourself

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep in mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

The console program has reached the end of its routine causing it to terminate. You need to put a [`Console.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Console.ReadKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the main method. This will wait for user input.

I'll usually do something like this

```
Sub Main()
  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit")
  Console.ReadKey()

  Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit")
  Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Console.ReadKey() should do what you are asking

put it before `End Sub`

refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user. The
>   pressed key is displayed in the console window.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally only an issue when debugging, so I add:

```
If Debugger.IsAttached Then _
  Console.ReadLine()
```

at the end of my console program `Main` routines.